# Monogame in Xamarin errors

Tags: xamarin, monogame

I have installed the latest Monogame (3.4) and the latest Xamarin updates. But even with this update there seem to be a number of references to DLL's that you have to remove manually. One reference is particular is very stubborn - I can't find where this file is referenced, so I keep getting this warning. It's not a problem but I'd like to know why this is happening. Is this something that has to be in Monogame for windows, but is not needed on mac?

**Error:**

```
Warning: The referenced library 'System.Core.dll' is not used from any code, skipping extraction of content resources.
```